# "Provisioning VM failed. Require plan information" when creating an image from image

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I was trying to create a GPU device from an image of another GPU device. But, Azure keeps showing me the same error:

[image]

**So, what exactly is the Plan information is Azure talking about?**. Also, is there some way to bring up a generalized VM? 
Template which I'm using: [though I am trying directly from the portal]

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualMachineName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualMachineSize": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualNetworkName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "networkInterfaceName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
            "type": "SecureString"
        },
        "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "diagnosticsStorageAccountId": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "publicIpAddressName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "publicIpAddressType": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "publicIpAddressSku": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "vnetId": "[resourceId('datasciencesdevNew','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
                },
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/dfbb6f84-8e85-42f9-862b-10d778e0b4a5/resourceGroups/datasciencesdev/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/Image-Aug10"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "fromImage",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "storageUri": "[concat('https://', parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/')]"
                    }
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            },
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIpAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('datasciencesdevNew','Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                    "id": "[resourceId('datasciencesdevNew', 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressSku')]"
            },
            "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "publicIpAllocationMethod": "[parameters('publicIpAddressType')]"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your template?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT Added the template in the question body

Comment: You can take a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines). There is the information about **Plan information**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add plan information to you VM definition. You can get it from your previous VM. it looks something like this:

```
"plan": {
  "publisher": "paloaltonetworks",
  "name": "bundle1",
  "product": "vmseries1"
}
```

this is at the root of the VM resource definition. name\product\publisher are here for reference

Comment: The template is not editable when trying to deploy from an image. Any idea how to make it editable?